# Adding suffix to duplicate index values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a df:

```
-0.01   -0.029064
-0.01   -0.032876
-0.01   -0.040795
-0.02   -0.027003
-0.02   -0.0315
```

Need to concat this with another frame, but get the error "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis". What I'd like is a df like this:

```
-0.01   -0.029064
-0.011   -0.032876
-0.012   -0.040795
-0.02   -0.027003
-0.021   -0.031589
```

(note: added suffixes after each duplicate index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get these cumulative counts, use `groupby` + `cumcount`.

```
v = df.groupby(df.index)\
      .cumcount()\
      .astype(str)\
      .str.replace('0', '')\
      .values

v 
array(['', '1', '2', '', '1'], dtype=object)
```

Concatenate with the index:

```
df.index = (df.index.values.astype(str) + v).astype(float)
df

           Value
-0.010 -0.029064
-0.011 -0.032876
-0.012 -0.040795
-0.020 -0.027003
-0.021 -0.031500
```

Comment: thanks this worked, for the purpose of assignment I just kept in floats, t1 = worst3.groupby(worst3.index).cumcount() ; 
v = (t1.replace('0','').values)/1000 ; worst3.index = worst3.index - v

Comment: @thomas.mac Fair enough, thanks for letting me know.